# git commit to github repo

Tags: git, github

I've been following the basics of git but something confuses me.

I created a repository on github.com. Then i opened my console and used the following commands:

> cd into/my/dir
>
> git add .
>
> git commit -m "some message"

Which gave me the following result:

> [master (root-commit) 96a358b] commit  35 files changed, 1494
>
> insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>
> ... and some other stuff

So far so good right? But nothing that i've been following so far shows me how to actually put the commit into the github repository...

I assume i have to add my github login/passwd somewhere, right? To be able to commit something to my github repo? But i can't really find any info about how to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow from this link to see how you can setup the necessary details on your box and push to a repo on Github : http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

Answer (score 0):

`git push` will do that, if you setup everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Git commands not only lets you commit but also you can add comments after committing your work using

```
git commit -m "Comment"
```

And after that

```
git push
```

lets you push the commits that you have made on your local branch to remote repository. This will ask for your authentication (Username/Password).